# enter specific venue in android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I want to enter specific venue while submitting form in android application. This venue details will be use in future for the routing purpose.

For example, the app will take the venue details for some event and send invites to the people, So user can navigate to that event venue from their current location.

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: An EditText perhaps? What have you tried? Send to server, save in db. Create api to fetch for other users?

Comment: But how can app define it is valid address or not ? because at the end it has to appear on the map for navigation purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you can follow the following flow:

1. User inputs address / venue where the event is.
2. Use the user input and build a request to Google's geocoding service:
   [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
   or
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Geocoding
3. If there are more address in response let the user select the right address. (optional)
4. Use response with lat / lng for Google Geocoding and save it in a database.

Think this will give you the most accurate result. As addition there are also address lookup API's available. but depending what you need and what country this probably will suit you're purpose.